# How to get average from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to get average of secs per file for given version. So if there are two runs of F1 for 1.3.0 version, then I should get average of both runs.

Here is my code for getting aggregate --

```
db.tc.aggregate([ 
    {
        $group:{
            _id:{platform:"win", version:"$version", filename:"$filename"},
            avgSecs: {$avg: "$secs"}
        }
    }
]);
```

But I notice, the avg values that I get are almost same across all files and versions.

Here is the [gist db](https://gist.github.com/mrudulp/81d336c7f80db0e4ee28c5ef77eff0a2) that contains the sample database.
Here is how the database looks like [image]

Note: Some versions have value for all files while some versions have values some of the files.

Comment: I think its just your data... I looked and EVERY set of `{plateform : "win"}` have a 60 sec and a 80 sec which is why they are all averaging to 70 sec

-- CONFIRMED, I changed the values of some and it shows different averages

Comment: @FrickeFresh agreed it's his data only.. i removed some of records and its giving different result..

Comment: @katch, your query is fine, don't get scared for the same results.